# Swift gradient from black to fully transparent

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, cagradientlayer

I am trying to apply a CAGradientLayer using swift, and I would like it to fade from black to transparent.

I thought putting any color with an `alpha: 0` would render the same "transparent" color. It is not the case. White with `alpha: 0` is still a bit white, red with `alpha: 0` is still a bit red...

I don't want any tint, just transparent. The black being less black to the point theres no color and you can fully see the view under it for example.

```
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor(hex: 0x000000, alpha: 0.4).cgColor,
                        UIColor(hex: 0x6D6D6D, alpha: 0.3).cgColor,
                        UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.0).cgColor]
gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.3, 1.0]
```

If I apply the layer over a gray picture, it's easy to see that its not transparent but white:

[image]

EDIT 1:

```
gradientLayer.frame = self.gradientView.bounds
gradientLayer.masksToBounds = true
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(1.0).cgColor, UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.0).cgColor]
gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
self.gradientView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using UIColor.clear.cgColor instead of UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.0).cgColor?

Comment: @JakeG yes I did, and instead of a white tint its a black tint...

Comment: you need transparent so why dont you use UIColor.clear ?

Comment: @iOSGeek I just said, I tried and its black

Comment: That's because `UIColor.clear` is actually a black color with an alpha value of 0. What worked for me when trying to fade from white to clear, was to fade from `(r: 255, g: 255, b: 255, a: 1)` to `(r: 255, g: 255, b: 255, a: 0.01)` (so still white but w/ a teeny tiny alpha value above 0. Same might work for black doing `(r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 1)` to `(r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 0.01)`

Comment: There are options for how the ending is drawn. If neither work, try making your own custom CGShading function, as per the Apple Guide. I usually have to tell it to "not draw last line" with kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation in the draw func

Comment: @LinusGeffarth, trying that right now. stephen, do you have any example ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(1.0).cgColor,
                            UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.0).cgColor]
    //gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.frame = myView.bound
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    myView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
```

It worked in my case.

Comment: Its very weird. I tried this and the black is still visible and the end. Instead of smoothly going to transparent, it stops line a "line".

Comment: I have edited my ans. Try adding `startPoint` and `endPoint`.

Comment: gradientLayer.frame = myView.frame insteed of this you need to set the myView.bound to work